# PHP: Finding differences in two multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I'm writing a script PHP script that creates a report of all the files of a chosen directory every 24 hours. I want to compare the latest report with the previous report to detect any edits of a file (by comparing md5 hash), deletion of a file, and creation of a file. I have the data of the two reports in two separate arrays. From what I can gather I will have to use the array_diff function. How do I: A) use this with a multidimensional array and B) label if the difference is either an edit, delete, or creation.

Example of data:

New Report:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => newhotfolder.gif
            [path] => images/newhotfolder.gif
            [type] => gif
            [size] => 1074
            [md5] => 123812asdkbqw98eqw80hasdas234234
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => image.gif
            [path] => images/attachtypes/image.gif
            [type] => gif
            [size] => 625
            [md5] => 7bbb66e191688a86b6f42a03bd412a6b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [file] => header.gif
            [path] => images/attachtypes/header.gif
            [type] => gif
            [size] => 625
            [md5] => 71291239asskf9320234kasjd8239393
        )
)
```

Old Report:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => newhotfolder.gif
            [path] => images/newhotfolder.gif
            [type] => gif
            [size] => 1074
            [md5] => 8375h5910423aadbef67189c6b687ff51c
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => image.gif
            [path] => images/attachtypes/image.gif
            [type] => gif
            [size] => 625
            [md5] => 7bbb66e191688a86b6f42a03bd412a6b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [file] => footer.gif
            [path] => images/attachtypes/footer.gif
            [type] => gif
            [size] => 625
            [md5] => 1223819asndnasdn2213123nasd921
        )
)
```

The function will have to be able to detect that the the md5 hash of "newhotfolder.gif" has changed, that the file "footer.gif" is deleted and that "header.gif" has been added. Perhaps return a third array like this?:

Comparison:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => newhotfolder.gif
            [path] => images/newhotfolder.gif
            [type] => gif
            [size] => 1074
            [md5] => 8375h5910423aadbef67189c6b687ff51c
            [status] => edited
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => image.gif
            [path] => images/attachtypes/image.gif
            [type] => gif
            [size] => 625
            [md5] => 7bbb66e191688a86b6f42a03bd412a6b
            [status] => same
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [file] => footer.gif
            [path] => images/attachtypes/footer.gif
            [type] => gif
            [size] => 625
            [md5] => 1223819asndnasdn2213123nasd921
            [status] => deleted
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [file] => header.gif
            [path] => images/attachtypes/header.gif
            [type] => gif
            [size] => 625
            [md5] => 71291239asskf9320234kasjd8239393
            [status] => new
        )
)
```

Comment: [http://us3.php.net/array_diff](http://us3.php.net/array_diff)

Comment: Per that link, "This function only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array. Of course you can check deeper dimensions by using array_diff($array1[0], $array2[0]);. "

Comment: @EmmyS Can't get that too work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multidimentional Array Foreach - Display in different tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576806/multidimentional-array-foreach-display-in-different-tables)

Answer (score 0):

first you should convert the objects into array,  i assume you can do it easily.
then you can use for each or for or while loop  yet i rather user for loop to identify sequence better.
And i agree with you an the function `array_diff()`
`array_diff()` is going to print out whatever the difference is so to check if they are equal you can say
 `array_diff($array1, $array2);`

and it should return a value as an array. if they are the same it comes out like this

```
array(0){
}
```

if they are not the same, whatever the difference in the array it will be output to the page in an array. i used same kinda logic as follows and i think you could use it as well.

```
$a1=array('val1'=>'abc', 'val2'=>'def', 'val3'=>'ghi', 'val4'=>'jkl');
$a2=array( 'val4'=>'jkl', 'val2'=>'def', 'val1'=>'abc', 'val3'=>'ghi' );

            if($a1==$a2 and sizeof(array_diff($a1, $a2))==0 and sizeof(array_diff($a2, $a1))==0) {
                echo "identical";
                //do your thing here
            }
```

this echos identical to the page.

Comment: This does not work. I'm dealing with a multidimensional array.